# What happens when you add items to a GtkTable beyond its specified size?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

GtkGrids are not available in GTK2, so you have to use GtkTables instead.

When you create a GtkTable, you specify the number of rows and columns it has. You can then add items to this table using `gtk_table_attach(_defaults)`. This function will allow you to add items to the table beyond its defined size. For example, you can create a table with three rows and successfully add items to the fourth row, without resizing the table.

Is it OK to do this, and what happens when you do this?

Answer (score 1):

The table is [silently resized](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtktable.c?h=gtk-2-24#n553).

Whenever you have such doubts, it is quicker to check the source code than ask.